# Vlc Media Problem in Fedora!

Tags: fedora, software-rec, selinux, vlc

I am using Fedora 13 and my VLC media player is showing this problem for the past one week. How do i rectify this error.

---

Summary:

SELinux is preventing /usr/bin/vlc from loading
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/codec/libdmo_plugin.so which requires text relocation.

Detailed Description:

The vlc application attempted to load
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/codec/libdmo_plugin.so which requires text relocation. This
is a potential security problem. Most libraries do not need this permission.
Libraries are sometimes coded incorrectly and request this permission. The
SELinux Memory Protection Tests
(http://people.redhat.com/drepper/selinux-mem.html) web page explains how to
remove this requirement. You can configure SELinux temporarily to allow
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/codec/libdmo_plugin.so to use relocation as a workaround,
until the library is fixed. Please file a bug report.

Allowing Access:

If you trust /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/codec/libdmo_plugin.so to run correctly, you
can change the file context to textrel_shlib_t. "chcon -t textrel_shlib_t
'/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/codec/libdmo_plugin.so'" You must also change the default
file context files on the system in order to preserve them even on a full
relabel. "semanage fcontext -a -t textrel_shlib_t
'/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/codec/libdmo_plugin.so'"

Fix Command:

chcon -t textrel_shlib_t '/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/codec/libdmo_plugin.so'

Additional Information:

Source Context                unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1
                              023
Target Context                system_u:object_r:lib_t:s0
Target Objects                /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/codec/libdmo_plugin.so [ file
                              ]
Source                        vlc
Source Path                   /usr/bin/vlc
Port                          
Host                          (removed)
Source RPM Packages           vlc-core-1.1.3-1.fc13
Target RPM Packages           vlc-core-1.1.3-1.fc13
Policy RPM                    selinux-policy-3.7.19-51.fc13
Selinux Enabled               True
Policy Type                   targeted
Enforcing Mode                Enforcing
Plugin Name                   allow_execmod
Host Name                     (removed)
Platform                      Linux (removed) 2.6.34.6-47.fc13.i686.PAE #1
                              SMP Fri Aug 27 09:29:49 UTC 2010 i686 i686
Alert Count                   3
First Seen                    Sat 04 Sep 2010 08:26:05 PM IST
Last Seen                     Sat 04 Sep 2010 08:35:40 PM IST
Local ID                      48840a90-fea4-403b-95a3-6cadc80b1a0a
Line Numbers

Raw Audit Messages

node=(removed) type=AVC msg=audit(1283612740.262:117): avc:  denied  { execmod } for  pid=9594 comm="vlc" path="/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/codec/libdmo_plugin.so" dev=sda2 ino=789070 scontext=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=system_u:object_r:lib_t:s0 tclass=file

node=(removed) type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1283612740.262:117): arch=40000003 syscall=125 success=no exit=-13 a0=4439000 a1=1e000 a2=5 a3=bfbe2480 items=0 ppid=1 pid=9594 auid=500 uid=500 gid=500 euid=500 suid=500 fsuid=500 egid=500 sgid=500 fsgid=500 tty=(none) ses=1 comm="vlc" exe="/usr/bin/vlc" subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 key=(null)

---

**Update** Well, i tried that now in terminal and nothing seems to happen.

[chandru.math@chandru ~]$ chcon -t textrel_shlib_t '/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/codec/libdmo_plugin.so

> 

It stops like this!

Comment: Hello @Chandru1 you will need to run it with sudo,  sudo chcon -t textrel_shlib_t '/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/codec/libdmo_plugin.so'  also make sure you have the single ' at the end of the line.

Comment: if I we're u, I would disable and remove SELinux, ofcourse it is not the answer to your problem, but it will solve your problem, just for your consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you run the fix command in the summary you posted?

```
sudo chcon -t textrel_shlib_t '/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/codec/libdmo_plugin.so'
```